# Get the phone system to automatically call me back?

Tags: phone

I have a weird problem with my phone which just got a new modem. I can call out but people complain they cannot call me. Supposedly it has been fixed, but how can I test this?

In the old days there used to be utility numbers whereby you could dial the number, hang up, then it would call you back.

Does this still exist? How can I get the system to call me back?

I know I can get a person to do it, but I don't want to hassle somebody to test my telephone.

Comment: This would vary from network to network.

Comment: It's called a "call-back" number used by telephone installers. I was an installer in the NE US. They have been largely discontinued since we all carry cellular phones and butt sets.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a service that requires 2 way authentication (like microsoft or google) some of their services will call you back and "give you a code", you can use this functionality to test your line number. (even with whatsapp you can do this doesnt even have to be a mobile phone) just specify you want VOICE message rather than SMS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it specified whether it's a cell, landline, or VOiP phone you're asking about, but my general answer should work for all three: call yourself from another phone.  If a cell phone, take it somewhere you can use a phone (there are still pay phones in larger cities; in the USA, they're often outside convenience stores that sell international cellular reload cards and burner phones).  If you let the cell phone ring a time or two and then hang up the pay phone, many pay phones will (or at least used to) return the coins you deposited.

If not a cell phone, call from your cell phone where you can hear the landline or VOiP phone ring or, ideally, answer it and hear your own voice coming back through the connection.